# Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-image, android-background

Even though I didn't choose photothumb.db as a drawable, I get an error saying photothumb.db should end with .xml or .png

my `profilesmaller` image is of type `png`

Below are my codes

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/profilesmaller"
    tools:context="charlenebuena.guest.HomeFragment">
</FrameLayout>
```

Below is my Gradle Console Message

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\Charlene Marie\AndroidStudioProjects\Guest\app\src\main\res\drawable\photothumb.db: Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.72 secs
```

Comment: change the location of photothumb.db from drawable to asset folder and it will solve the problem

Comment: @Char whether the image in drawable had an jpg or png extension in file name

Comment: whether photothumb is an image or a database file?

Comment: you need to create it manually check my answer and mark it as correct one if it helped thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Android accepts only .png, .jpg, .gif and .xml files as drawable resources. If you have file .db file then put that file in assets folder.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem after I converted .png icons to .webp format. The file was created in the xxhdpi folder and not used. I didn't remember creating or using photothumbs.db in any of my app's xml and java files. The error was cleared after simply deleting the photothumbs.db file. Create a backup copy of the file anyway for safety before deleting it.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when somehow (I have no idea how) one of my asset files got ended up in

```
.../app/src/main/res/assets/model.tflite
```

When it should have been at

```
.../app/src/main/assets/model.tflite
```

Moving it back fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove photothumb.db file from drawable to asset directory. If asset directory is not there then right click on 
main > New > directory > assets and then create.Place your db file there and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

just check if there are weird directory names under in  /app/src/main/res/

$ ls
drawable            mipmap-hdpi
drawable-hdpi           mipmap-mdpi
drawable-ldpi           mipmap-xhdpi
drawable-mdpi           mipmap-xxhdpi
drawable-xhdpi          mipmap-xxxhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi         raw
drawable-xxxhdpi        rawwhilemusic.mp3 winner.mp3 **<- (after deleting this directory no error)**
layout              values
mipmap-anydpi-v26

Answer (score -2):

Just change your image file extension from something(like ico etc) to png.
It will work.

Comment: Nothing recommended.